# Laravel error in logs caused by cache (failed to open stream)

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-8

I have an error since some weeks.
This error is displayed in Laravel 8.12 logs.

I've used `php artisan cache:clear` but this error persist.

```
[previous exception] [object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/home/runcloud/webapps/site/storage/framework/cache/data/dc/31/dc3113bd6a52987a73ccaa66cce116cc20bb5f87): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/runcloud/webapps/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/runcloud/webapps/yubigeek/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(187): file_put_contents()
```

I typed these commands :

```
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

The problem persists...

This error is entirely random, the website works well but sometimes I get a 500 error and the logs give me the error mentioned above.

The config for cache driver is `file`.

I don't know what to do or where to look.

Comment: Like Rui already said, this is a permission issue and chmod will fix this.

Comment: Make sure This directory exists : "/home/runcloud/webapps/site/storage/framework/cache/data/dc/31/"

Also make sure /home/runcloud/webapps/site/storage is owned by you

Comment: @Birdy The problem persists after 1 hour, I just saw the same error in the Laravel logs.

Comment: @pirmax  suspect you have a cron job or schedule running that is using elevated privileges, as a result it is logging to the log file thus causing the permissions to change. I would check what schedules or crons you have running or maybe supervisord?

Answer (score 0):

Please, on your terminal, inside your root project, run this commands:

```
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

find ./ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

These are the right permissions for a Laravel project.

Comment: I typed these commands, the problem persists after 1 hour, I just saw the same error in the Laravel logs.